# Swift - How to properly get data from REST API to Label in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an iOS app to get data from API that I want to show the user in a Label.

So far I have this:

```
func getJoke(completion: @escaping (ChuckNorrisResponse) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("Something fucked up")
                return
            }
            
            var result: ChuckNorrisResponse?
            do {
                result = try JSONDecoder().decode(ChuckNorrisResponse.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print("Fucked up to convert \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            guard let joke = result else {
                return
            }
            
            completion(joke)
        }.resume()
    }
```

And in the ViewController

```
func setNewJoke() {
        jokesProvier.getJoke { joke in
            self.JokeLabel.text = joke.value
        }
```

But it doesn't like that I try to edit the text in the Label inside the closure.
It shows error - UILabel.Text must be used from main thread only.

I cannot find anywhere how should I do this properly so it works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.JokeLabel.text = joke.value }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend calling the completion handler on the main thread. So instead of

```
completion(joke)
```

do

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(joke) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, as Aaron stated - you have to pass the closure to the main thread with `DispatchQueue.main.async`. The reason is that `URLSession.shared.dataTask` completionHandler runs on the thread different from main and `self.JokeLabel.text = joke.value` is an UI update - you're changing the text on the label, and UIKit requires you to update the screen on the main thread! That's why you have to pass label update to the main thread. Trying to update it on the thread different from main will result in undefined behaviour - it may work, it may freeze, it may crash.
So, whenever you're doing something on the background thread and at some point want to update the UI always pass this job to the main thread
 Hope this helps